# Access violation on struct

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, struct, access-violation

I'm getting a "Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008." with this code:

main.xcpp

```
Penguin::Game game;
game.memory = {};
game.memory.permanentSize = 1024*64;
game.memory.permanent = VirtualAlloc(0, game.memory.permanentSize, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
game.Start();
```

game.Start()

```
input = (Input *)memory.permanent;
*input = {}; // << Access violation reading location.
```

Game struct

```
struct Game
{
    struct Memory
    {
        uint64  permanentSize;
        void    *permanent;
    };

    Memory memory;

    Input *input;

    void Start();
};
```

However. If i try:

```
int *i = (int *)memory.permanent;
*i = 10;
```

It works.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You have a debugger, learn how to use it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using assignment operator of `Input` class on uninitialized memory you allocated with `VirtualAlloc`. That's what's causing the crash. Assignment operator generally expects an `Input` object in *valid state* on its left-hand size. You are passing a block of completely uninitialized raw memory, which triggers undefined behavior.

Assignment operator always assumes that the left-hand side contains old data, which in general case has to be somehow disposed of before storing new data in its place. But in your case the left-hand side operand contains garbage. Trying to destroy that garbage using "normal" methods leads to a crash. Your call stack shows that you have a `std::map` inside your `Input`. `std::map::clear()` is what crashes.

In other words, what you are doing is equivalent to this

```
std::map<int, int> *p = (std::map<int, int> *) malloc(sizeof *p);
p->clear();
```

The above will also lead to undefined behavior (a crash, most likely), for the very same reason it crashes in your code.

Don't attempt to use assignment operator (and any other non-trivial method or operation) on raw memory, i.e. on non-constructed objects.

If you want to use assignment operator on `*input`, you have to construct a 
valid `Input` object in that memory first. Placement new can help you with it

```
input = new (memory.permanent) Input{};
```

Now `*input` is a valid, properly constructed object of type `Input`, which will also behave properly on the left-hand side (or any side) of assignment

```
*input = {}; // OK
```

Actually, the above new-expression will also do what you are trying to do with your assignment operator, meaning that there's no need in that assignment anymore.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you very much for this information.